# Find the limit of $\frac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2(y-2)}$ when $(x,y)\to(1,2)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-1)^2+\sin^2 {(y-2)}}
$$

[According to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A((x-1)(y-2))%2F((x-1)%5E2%2B(sin%20(y-2))%5E2)%2F%2F%5D%2C%20%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ax%2Cy%2F%2F%5D%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2C2%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D), this limit does not exist.
I know that if the limit does not exist than it should show different results when approaching $(1,2)$ from different directions.
How can I prove this? I tried approaching from different directions but I can never find the limit (keep getting $"\frac{0}{0}"$).

Comment: In any open neighborhood of the point $(1,2)$, we may find a coordinate pair $(x,y)$ such that $\sin^2(y - 2) = 1 - x$. The expression, rewritten as $\dfrac{y - 2}{1 + \dfrac{\sin^2(y - 2)}{x - 1}}$, diverges.

Comment: If $y=2+z$ and $x=1+z$ with $z\to0$ then the ratio is $z+o(z)\to0$. If $y=2+z$ and $x=1-z^2$ with $z\to0$ then the ratio is $z^3/(z^2-\sin^2z)\sim6/z\to\pm\infty$. QED.

Comment: @StevenHarding The limit is understood as being restricted to the domain of definition of the function, naturally.

Comment: Well, then use my observation to make the natural argument that the modulus of the function exceeds an arbitrary epsilon for every neighborhood of the point (1,2).

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot that the $(x-1)$ is to the power of 2

Comment: Consider the limit along the path $y = x + 1$; it should be $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Along the path $y = x + 1$, we evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \dfrac{(x - 1)^2}{(x - 1)^2 + \sin^2(x - 1)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \dfrac{1}{1 + \left(\dfrac{\sin(x - 1)}{x - 1}\right)^2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: So the limit, if it exists, equals $1/2$. This is not enough, in my opinion.

Comment: Can you find a path that contradicts it?

Comment: The trivial paths $y = 2$ or $x = 1$ contradict this limit.